# SELECT the first date in which 3 consecutive entries are between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, select, subquery, mariadb-10.2

I would like to know the first date of the first 3 consecutive entries that are between two dates. Based on my SQLFiddle, I would expect the output to be '2021-01-24'.

I've looked at many examples but can't get them to work.

This query is not working how I want it to, I can't figure out the missing piece of my query. Here is the SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/935fbd/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    logDate
FROM
    FoodLog
WHERE
    studentID = '1329' AND logDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-05-01'
GROUP BY
    logDate
HAVING
    COUNT(logDate) = 3
```

I've tried working with the following, but can't figure out how to limit the search to studentID='1329' or my date range:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    f.id,
    f.logDate
FROM
    FoodLog f,
    (
    SELECT
        f1.logDate START,
        f2.logDate NEXT
    FROM
        FoodLog f1,
        FoodLog f2
    WHERE
        f2.logDate <= DATE_ADD(f1.logDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND f2.logDate > f1.logDate
) f2
WHERE
    f.logDate = f2.start OR(
        f.logDate = f2.next AND f2.start IS NOT NULL
    )
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Are you using 8.x so you can use window functions?

Comment: @Barmar - Server version: 10.2.34-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server, Protocol version: 10

Comment: *I would like to know the first date of the first 3 consecutive entries that are between two dates.* Does all 3 dates must posess in a range, or only returned date?

Comment: @Akina All 3 dates need to be consecutive and between two dates. I need to return the first date that begins the series of 3. I hope I answered your question

Comment: Window functions were added in 10.2, so you should be able to use them.

Comment: Where in your query is the requirement that the dates be consecutive?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'or'?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what 'or' you're referring to. I didn't know how to correctly make the dates consecutive.

Comment: The word only occurs once in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT logDate
    FROM FoodLog
    WHERE logDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-05-01'),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT logDate, LEAD(logDate, 2) OVER (ORDER BY logDate) next2date
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT MIN(logDate) logDate 
FROM cte2 
WHERE DATEDIFF(next2date, logDate) = 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e7c72fb69d61dc7b0ad8d1f166b2b618)